# Cutted photo off when is big one. Nodejs, express, graphql

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nginx, graphql

When I upload a big photo then it's cut off. These are a few lines where I save the photo on the backend side. It happens only when a photo is big (more than 2MB). I use nodejs, express, graphql with apollo-upload-client. All is running on docker with nginx.

```
const { filename, createReadStream } = await input.photo;

if (isFunction(createReadStream)) {
   const fileStream = createReadStream();
   const trimedFilename = trim(filename);

   fileStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${eventFolderPath}/${trimedFilename}`));                        
}
```

The photo looks like that:
[corrupted photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCwfP.png)

Comment: Please check the value of `client_max_body_size` in your nginx configuration. It kind of sounds like you are sending more data than allowed with that config. Also it sounds like your Browser does not send a `Content-Length` header meaning that nginx is not able to decide to cancel the request with an Entity too Large error upfront.

Comment: not, you're simply not waiting for end of uploading ... search for node.js uploading answers/examples